# pandas multiply using dictionary values across several columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'b': [5,4,3,3,4],
    'c': [3,2,4,3,10],
    'd': [3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

And the following list of parameters:

```
params = {'a': 2.5, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 1.3, 'd': 0.9}
```

Produce the following desired output:

```
   a  b   c  d  output
0  1  5   3  3    24.1
1  2  4   2  2    21.4
2  3  3   4  1    22.6
3  4  3   3  1    23.8
4  5  4  10  1    38.4
```

I have been using this to produce the result:

```
df['output'] = [np.sum(params[col] * df.loc[idx, col] for col in df)
                 for idx in df.index]
```

However, this is a very slow approach and I'm thinking there has to be a better way using built-in pandas functionality.

I also thought of this:

```
# Line up the parameters
col_sort_key = list(df)
params_sorted = sorted(params.items(), key=lambda k: col_sort_key.index(k[0]))

# Repeat the parameters *n* number of times
values = [v for k, v in params_sorted]
values = np.array([values] * df.shape[0])

values
array([[ 2.5,  3. ,  1.3,  0.9],
       [ 2.5,  3. ,  1.3,  0.9],
       [ 2.5,  3. ,  1.3,  0.9],
       [ 2.5,  3. ,  1.3,  0.9],
       [ 2.5,  3. ,  1.3,  0.9]])

# Multiply and add
product = df[col_sort_key].values * values
product
array([[  2.5,  15. ,   3.9,   2.7],
       [  5. ,  12. ,   2.6,   1.8],
       [  7.5,   9. ,   5.2,   0.9],
       [ 10. ,   9. ,   3.9,   0.9],
       [ 12.5,  12. ,  13. ,   0.9]])

np.sum(product, axis=1)
array([ 24.1,  21.4,  22.6,  23.8,  38.4])
```

But that seems a bit convoluted! Any thoughts on a native pandas try?

Comment: Points to Jezrael since his ended up being fastest for my actual use case. My old approach was 65 times slower than this new one. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: what about matrix vector multiplication in numpy?
This would end up with something like: np.matmul(df.as_matrix(),np.array(2.5, 3.0, 1.3, 0.9) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) + [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(**params).mul(df).sum(1)
print (df1)
0    24.1
1    21.4
2    22.6
3    23.8
4    38.4
dtype: float64
```

And [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) + `Series` constructor:

```
df1 = df.dot(pd.Series(params))
print (df1)
0    24.1
1    21.4
2    22.6
3    23.8
4    38.4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please note that for the `df1 = df.dot(pd.Series(params))` method **the ordering of the params dict matters**. The dot-product does not take into account column names, only column order.

Answer (score 8):

```
(pd.Series(params)*df).sum(1)
Out[816]: 
0    24.1
1    21.4
2    22.6
3    23.8
4    38.4
dtype: float64
```

More info:

```
pd.Series(params)
Out[817]: 
a    2.5
b    3.0
c    1.3
d    0.9
dtype: float64

(pd.Series(params)*df)
Out[818]: 
      a     b     c    d
0   2.5  15.0   3.9  2.7
1   5.0  12.0   2.6  1.8
2   7.5   9.0   5.2  0.9
3  10.0   9.0   3.9  0.9
4  12.5  12.0  13.0  0.9
```

For your example, you can use `dot` as well

```
df.values.dot(np.array(list(params.values())))
Out[827]: array([ 24.1,  21.4,  22.6,  23.8,  38.4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
(df*params).sum(axis=1)
```

Tested on pandas 1.2.4.